# css or Javascript repeat image without cropping it

Tags: css, image

Is it possible in css to repeat (repeat-y) your image on a background of a div-tag (or other tag) but without cropping it.
So when the image doesn't fully fit in the tag the tag's height increases.

Comment: Short answer, not with css. You could probably achieve something like that using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.
You can specify `min-height` to that element equal to the background image's height, but that will not guarantee that the first time the image repeats that repeat will be 100% visible too.

If you want all the repeats to be visible at 100%, you'll have to use some javascript.

Edit (since question was updated) : If you're OK with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/ytXd6/

Basically you set `min-height` and for multiple repeats you divide the height by the image's height and add the remainder so that the div's height will be always multiple to the image's height.